# Getting used to either US or EN International keyboard layout

Tags: keyboard, internationalization

I will buy a new Macbook soon. I am german and used to the german keyboard layout:
[image: german mac keyboard]
Since I do alot of coding and many special characters are placed inconveniently on the german keyboard (e.g. `{` and `}`) I will purchase either a US or a EN International keyboard.

I am tempted to buy the standard US one, because I like to believe that this is the way the ANSI has conceived the keyboard layout to be. However, I am concerned that I will not get used to the small <kbd>return</kbd> key, and will accidently press <kbd>\</kbd> often.

[image: US standard keyboard]
[image: US international keyboard]

What can you recommend me? Do you think I will get used to the small <kbd>return</kbd> quickly?

Comment: i take the us international on macbook and on my iMac as bluetooth

Answer (score 2, accepted):

US Standard.

For one, Apple only offer the option of US Standard in some territories now. US International exists for its close resemblance to UK version. Secondly, US Standard is the pervalant QWERTY across countries regardless of the manufacturer. Plus, symmetry. I guess if you need to re-learn where all the symbol keys are anyways, why not use the keyboard that doesn't have a symbol key left of "Z"? It's just better.

If you want you can install Karabiner, and remap "\" into "return" key, and map option+"\" back to "\". This way no worries about that annoyance.

Comment: I don't think this is accurate.  My impression is that most of the world outside the US and Japan uses ISO standard keyboards with the extra key. They are never going to adopt the US ANSI standard.  Check http://support.apple.com/kb/ht2841

Comment: English speaking countries other than UK and Ireland all use US keyboard. "Apple's US International" is actually different from common "US International". Common US-I doesn't have a key between Shift and Z. In this way A-US-I is closer to British keyboard. This apple page is a bit misleading in what it doesn't say, which is, if Apple doesn't make a localized keyboard for a market, it stocks its stores with US Standard. If you are in a QWERTZ or AZERTY country, you have a choice of US-S or US-I. If you in say China, you can only pick up US-S.

Comment: Could you provide a reference url for the "common US-I" keyboard?  I had not heard of that before.

Comment: Apple US International keyboard is a breed of it's own. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/QWERTY#Apple_International_English_Keyboard

Comment: I think you are confusing the US International software layout with a hardware keyboard.  The US International layout can be used with any of the ISO, ANSI, JIS keyboards.  Apple's US International is just a standard ISO hardware keyboard.

Comment: You are right about ANSI keyboards in China.  I think everyone in Europe, Latin America, Africa, Russia, and the Arabic/Persian area will normally be using an ISO keyboard with the extra key.  US, Canada, Japan, Korea, China, India, Australia will normally be using ANSI.

Comment: I have had a Dell US International like this a lifetime ago. http://liliputing.com/2009/02/dells-international-keyboard-for-the-inspiron-mini-9.html

Comment: After about 11 months I can say: US standard was the best decision! Getting used to it took a week maximum.

Answer (score 1):

The US one is fine. There won't be any problems with the return key after a couple of days of use. Your main worry is probably locations of symbols: @, ?, / etc.